# Are the minimal primes of the same height

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring and let $I$ be an ideal of height $n$. Is it true that height of $P$ is $n$ for all minimal primes over $I$?

If the answer to the above question is negative, then is it true for Gorenstein rings?

Comment: We know that there exists a prime $Q$ necessarily minimal over $I$ such that height of $Q$ is $n$

Comment: i dont think the above statement is true even for CM rings, but i dont have a counterexample.

Comment: @YACP, thanks, that was really easy but somehow i was not able to construct a counterexample.

Comment: @YACP Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3):

Take $R=K[X,Y,Z]$ and $I=(X,Y)\cap (Z)$.